# IE freezes due to JavaScript endless garbage collection

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, infinite-loop

I have a web page that started freezing the browser recently, so I ran a UI Responsiveness report from the F12 Developer Tools and found an obvious infinite loop of garbage collection that went on for 10 seconds before IE auto-detected the page as unresponsive ("a long running script...").

[image]

[image]

<sub>(the scrollbar on this is quite long)</sub>

How do I go about debugging this? I've never seen anything like it before. Nothing in the source JavaScript for the page even has the word "garbage" in it.

P.S. I don't know why it started doing it today, as the changelog in source control shows nothing related to the web page in question.

Thanks.

Comment: http://nodesimplified.com/memory-management-garbage-collection-javascript/

Comment: Hard to spot a memory issue based on a picture... I do see an awfully large number of `style.xyz` calls, which is probably not helping your performance any.

Comment: Yeah, that is from our UI framework code (which hasn't been updated recently), which unfortunately does a ton of obfuscation so I have to work hard to even find my own JavaScript files referenced to put breakpoints on.
It's gotta be some other referenced file that would seem unrelated, because there is no other explanation since this issue started recently.

Comment: It turns out that foreign key violations in the database layer caused bad model data to get loaded. The garbage collector spam symptom is still curious.